# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone help me on this issue?

I am printing Logcat. but i can't reproduce this issue. few of my users getting this issue.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {myPackage/myPackage.FragmentViewer}: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537,
>   result=-1, data=Intent { }} to activity
>   {myPackage/myPackage.FragmentViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   uri --------- Stack trace ---------
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4156)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>   ------------------------------- --------- Cause --------- java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { }} to
>   activity {myPackage/myPackage.FragmentViewer}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4933)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4142)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

This is copied from my users Logcat value and he is using  Android version 6.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It will be useful if you also post you `onActivityResult` block.